# Cardinals and generic extensions

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, forcing

Let us consider a model of ZFC $M$, a forcing $\mathbb{P}\in M$. If $G$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-generic filter over $M$ we can construct the generic extension $M[G]$ of $M$. 
Given any cardinal number $\kappa$ in $M[G]$ it is clear $\kappa$ is a cardinal in $M$ since $M$ cannot since more bijections than $M[G]$.

My question is, suppose for example $\omega_1^M$ is a cardinal number in $M[G]$, then $\omega_1^M=\omega_1^{M[G]}$? And in general, if $\kappa^M$ is a cardinal in $M[G]$ then $\kappa^M=\kappa^{M[G]}$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily check that $\omega_1^M\le \omega_1^{M[G]}$ holds as an ordinal. Moreover, since $\omega_1^M$ is cardinal in $M[G]$, $\omega_1^M$ must be an uncountable ordinal. Thus $M[G]\models \omega_1^{M[G]}\le \omega_1^M$ so they are equal. (It follows from the fact that if $\alpha$ is uncountable ordinal then $\alpha\ge\omega_1$. Take $\alpha=\omega_1^M$ and relativize the formula to $M[G]$.)

I don't know the meaning of $\kappa^M$, because $\kappa^M$ is just $\kappa$. However if you have intended such as $\omega_2^M$, it does not hold in general. For example, you can collapse $\omega_1^M$ to a countable ordinal and preserve cardinals above $\omega_1^M$. In that case $\omega_2^M = \omega_1^{M[G]}$ so $\omega_2^M$ is cardinal in $M[G]$ but $\omega_2^M\neq \omega_2^{M[G]}$.

Comment: @Ergonvi To state the second paragraph in other words, for any $\alpha$ we have $\aleph_\alpha^{M[G]}\geq \aleph_\alpha^M$ and strict inequality is possible.

Comment: How can we prove $\aleph_\alpha^{M[G]}\geq \aleph_\alpha^M$ ?

Comment: @Ergonvi Since $\omega_1^{M[G]}$ is an uncountable ordinal in $M$.

Comment: Is the following proof of $\aleph_\alpha^{M[G]}\geq \aleph_\alpha^M$ correct?

If $\beta\in \aleph_\alpha^M$ then $\beta\in M$ and $\beta<\aleph_\alpha$. Since $M\subset M[G]$ then $\beta\in M[G]$ and ·$\beta<\aleph_\alpha$ and thus $\alpha \in \aleph_\alpha^{M[G]}$. Due to $\aleph_\alpha^M\subset \aleph_\alpha^{M[G]}$ we can conclude $\aleph_\alpha^M\leq \aleph_\alpha^{M[G]}$.

Comment: @Ergonvi In general, we have the following: for any forcing extension $M\subseteq N$, and any set $A\in M$, we have $\vert A\vert^N\le\vert A\vert ^M$. The proof is easy: if there is a bijection between $A$ and $\kappa$ in $M$, then that very bijection is again a bijection between $A$ and $\kappa$ in $N$. So basically, "sets get smaller."